# Blank Bar Charts in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have a df - Wards - that contains the number of different events that happen  on each ward of a hospital. I just want a simple bar chart of the totals of these events. I have used plotly before - I am no means an expert (evidently!) but I can't figure out where I am going wrong! With the code below I am seeing anything with fig.show(). I added the fig.write_image command to test - this returns the correct graph - but I can't figure out why my fig.show() command doesn't work

```
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = px.bar(Wards, x='Ward', y='Total_Tasks')
fig.write_image("fig1.png")
fig.show()
```

Comment: `savefig` and `show` both "flush" the drawing.  After either one, you start with a blank slate.

Comment: i put the savefig in to test... it saves a blank image - without it there is see no plot

Comment: What is `px`?  I must not be up on the abbreviations.

Comment: Thank Tim - Please see edits to the OP - px is my abbreviation for plotlyexpress

Comment: OK, so the lesson is that the `x` and `y` parameters are supposed to be the data points, not the axis labels.  That's probably the root of your problem.

Comment: Thanks - Ward and Total_Tasks are columns in my DF - Wards. I understood bar could take a DF as and input and you could proviude the column names as inputs.... this works as the fig1.png is created.... but I can'e see why fig show doesn't work

Comment: @SammyG Your figure setup is fine with `px.bar(Wards, x='Ward', y='Total_Tasks')`. You can run `fig.show()` as many times as you want too. So the problem lies elsewhere - most likely `how` you're using `Plotly`. Is it in  JupyterLab? Some other `IDE`. The fact that `fig.write_image("fig1.png")` produces a figure strongly indicates that it's your IDE or visualization tool that isn't properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your code but of course I don't have the data, so I made some up and I also didn't know for sure what modules you are importing, so I used the help at:
https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/
but anyway, here is what I came up with
that seems to work.

```
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = px.bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[1, 3, 2])
plt.savefig('fig1.png',bbox_inches="tight",dpi=600)
fig.show()
```

Comment: bar is supposed to take a df as as an input - can you edit so you parse a df to bar? I have updated my code to show the libraries I am using (sorry)

Comment: @SammyG regarding the df, I think you will find exactly the help you are looking for at:  https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/   They have a df chart and some code to go with it.